# Keep app audio playing in background on Android

Tags: firefox, android, audio-streaming, vimeo

I listen to video lectures on apps like Vimeo&Dailymotion, and it's frustrating not being able to do other things on my device while listening, like I do on my laptop. As soon as the Youtube/Vimeo/DM app goes into the background, it stops playing. Ditto for videos playing in browser tabs, even if I move to another tab it stops, presumably to save battery life.

Looking for a way to maybe suppress the "inactive" or sleep state which apps go into when they're not in the foreground. My device is rooted, is there an app for this?

Firefox used to allow audio on other tabs to continue playing, now that doesn't work either. Would be great if there was a config flag or setting to let people choose...

---

I'd have thought this was a common problem other people also had?

A bad solution that I temporarily use, is to download vids using the video apps for various websites(Tubemate for youtube, Dailymotion official app), but then I need to wait until the whole vid downloads.

Comment: Floating Browser? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gpc.myweb.hinet.net.PopupWeb&hl=en